# update latest php on CentOS6.5

Tags: php, centos

I have a `CentOS6.5` server, and my php version is 5.6.0, I want to update my php higher, the latest version `php5.6.13` is the best.

Before I did it, I updated yum repository.

I used `yum` to update it, but I failed.

I input this command `# yum update php`,

and it showed this message:`No Packages marked for Update`

How shall I do?

Thanks for your answers and recommendations.

Comment: just because a newer version is available in source form doesn't mean it's available for your version of centos. centos/redhat don't jump major versions of a package until the next major release of the distro.

Comment: You mean if I wanna install a newer version, the best way is download the php from `php.net` and make it ?

Comment: that'd be one way. maybe there's a non-official repo that has up-to-date versions, but this site is for programming questions, not "how to install software".

Comment: `yum install php56w` try this